# How can i run FastAPI application and Telegram bot on the same code

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi, telegram

I have a Python application that utilizes FastAPI for handling webhooks, and I'm trying to integrate a Telegram bot to my app but i can't run the telegram server, i tried to use threading. However, The Telegram bot isn't working and i get this error

```
Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8383 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Bot is running...
Exception in thread Thread-2 (run_telegram_bot):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/yosef/uni/Uni chat store/index.py", line 23, in run_telegram_bot
    TelegramNotification().lunch_bot()
  File "/Users/yosef/uni/Uni chat store/utils/telegram/send_notifictions.py", line 51, in lunch_bot
    application.run_polling(1.0)
  File "/Users/yosef/.local/share/virtualenvs/Uni_chat_store-eDiP6l1M/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 836, in run_polling
    return self.__run(
  File "/Users/yosef/.local/share/virtualenvs/Uni_chat_store-eDiP6l1M/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1007, in __run
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2 (run_telegram_bot)'.
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py:1018: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Updater.start_polling' was never awaited
  self._invoke_excepthook(self)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

this is the Telegram launch function from TelegramNotification class

```
def lunch_bot(self):
        application = Application.builder().token(self.BOT_TOKEN).build()
        print('Bot is running...')

        # Commands
        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', self.start))

        # Run bot
        application.run_polling(1.0)
```

and this is my index.py file

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import whatsapp_webhook, payment_method_form
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn
from utils.telegram.send_notifictions import TelegramNotification
import threading

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Allows all origins
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Allows all methods
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Allows all headers
)

app.include_router(whatsapp_webhook.router)
app.include_router(payment_method_form.router)


def run_telegram_bot():
    TelegramNotification().lunch_bot()

# run the whatsapp webhook 
def run_whatsapp_webhook():
    uvicorn.run("index:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8383)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    threading.Thread(target=run_whatsapp_webhook).start()
    threading.Thread(target=run_telegram_bot).start()
```

Comment: Do you need them to run in the same process? Otherwise, in these cases, it's often easier to just run two Python processes, one with your telegram bot and one with the FastAPI application.

Comment: Yes, I do. I want to combine two APIs in one server, one for WhatsApp and one for Telegram. I ended up using the HTTPS format for the Telegram API instead of the Telegram library.